# Erro 174 - O evento somente será aceito após a data de início da obrigatoriedade do empregador ao eSocial

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Gostaria de saber se mais alguém recebe esse erro quando envia o "S-1000" para o ambiente de produção restrita, e como é possível solucioná-lo. Estou finalizando a estrutura mas não consigo enviar com sucesso uma única vez.

```
<retornoEvento>
  <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/retornoEvento/v1_2_0">
    <retornoEvento Id="...">
      <ideEmpregador>
        <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
        <nrInsc>...</nrInsc>
      </ideEmpregador>
      <recepcao>
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <dhRecepcao>2018-07-04T10:07:14.837</dhRecepcao>
        <versaoAppRecepcao>0.1.0-A0317</versaoAppRecepcao>
        <protocoloEnvioLote>...</protocoloEnvioLote>
      </recepcao>
      <processamento>
        <cdResposta>401</cdResposta>
        <descResposta>Conteudo do evento inválido.</descResposta>
        <versaoAppProcessamento>10.0.1-A3199</versaoAppProcessamento>
        <dhProcessamento>2018-07-04T10:07:14.89</dhProcessamento>
        <ocorrencias>
          <ocorrencia>
            <tipo>1</tipo>
            <codigo>174</codigo>
            <descricao>O evento somente será aceito após a data de início da obrigatoriedade do empregador ao eSocial.</descricao>
            <localizacao/>
          </ocorrencia>
        </ocorrencias>
      </processamento>
    </retornoEvento>
  </eSocial>
</retornoEvento>
```

Comment: Este [link](https://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/topic/43683-174-o-evento-somente-ser%C3%A1-aceito-ap%C3%B3s-a-data-de-in%C3%ADcio-da-obrigatoriedade-do-empregador-ao-esocial/) te ajuda ?

Comment: Ajuda! Pelo menos mudaram os erros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o link fornecido por [LP. Gonçalves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/43183/lp-gon%C3%A7alves) encontrei o problema, a data de Inicio precisa estar em um mês especifico para funcionar, conforme visto no forum:

> Em produção ou Teste?  Manda o Arquivo Xml, já formatado se possível.
> Em Teste só será aceito eventos posteriores a 2016-01
>
> Em Produção só será aceito eventos posteriores a 2018-01 (Respeitando
> os meses das fases)
>
> ...
>
> o IniValid após atualização do ambiente de produção restrita do
> eSocial do dia 26/06 foi alterado de 2016-01 para 2017-01 seguindo as
> mesmas regras de faseamento do ambiente de produção..
>
> http://portal.esocial.gov.br/noticias/testes-com-o-faseamento-na-producao-restrita-terao-ano-base-2017

[Link pro forum](https://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/topic/43683-174-o-evento-somente-ser%C3%A1-aceito-ap%C3%B3s-a-data-de-in%C3%ADcio-da-obrigatoriedade-do-empregador-ao-esocial/)